# Is there a way to get a collectionViews frame from a collectionviewcell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to use

`-preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes` inside the `UICollectionviewCell` subclass we are writing.

Currently we already had a weak pointer to out `parentViewController` and I try to set the collectionViewcell frame width to be the same as `parentViewcontroller.view.frame.size.width`.

I don't want to have a pointer to the `parentViewController` from the `CollectionViewCell` subclass as having a reference to the parentviewcontroller is a bad idea.

My question is....

Is there a simple and ideal way to get the frame of collectionviewcell's super view from inside the `collectionViewcell` class?

Comment: if you dont want to use the `.superview` in the answer, use delegate instead..

Comment: @0yeoj and have a method in the delegate to get the frame?

Comment: Yes, but it probably over kill.. why dont you use `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` did you have some modification of frame in your viewController?

Comment: @0yeoj the reason why we can't use the mainScreen bounds is because we use a split view controller for iPhone 6 Plus and iPad devices also the only frame modification happens when you change orientation

Comment: Okay, that explains it.. Then `delegate` if not `.superview` is your option..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be use the parent view then you don't need any reference. You can do like this:

```
CGFloat width = self.superview.frame.size.width;
```

And as @Ralfonso pointed out in the comments:

Also, if you want to get the superview size immediately after being added to a view hierarchy, override `didMoveToSuperview:` and access the superview property. If it's nil, the view has been removed from the superview. If non-nil, the view has been added to the superview's hierarchy.

Comment: Also, if you want to get the superview size immediately after being added to a view hierarchy, override `didMoveToSuperview` and access the `superview` property. If it's nil, the view has been removed from the superview. If non-nil, the view has been added to the superview's hierarchy.

Comment: @Otávio is trying to access the superview a viable solution?

Comment: @Ralfonso so when we write the over ride function do I have a iVar in my collectionviewcell subclass and assign the superview to that?

Comment: @ShabarinathPabba if you want to keep a reference to the superview just keep in mind that you should use `weak`. Anyway I don't think that you need to a reference to the superview, you could use it just like the first example in my answer. And yes it a viable solution, not elegant but if you need to know the superview width that is usually the way to go.

Comment: @ShabarinathPabba Concerning the superview ivar in the UICollectionViewCell subclass - yes, the superview ivar is already a member because it is a UIView subclass. The `superview` property, however, is `readonly` and you shouldn't attempt to modify the backing ivar directly.